# Un-Upvoting Comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-voting

We should have the ability to un-upvote comments that we had previously voted on, within a reasonable timeframe.  Sometimes my hand slips and I accidentally upvote something, or I blindly upvote Jon Skeet's comments out of habit.

Comment: @balpha: If you're going to close all these questions as duplicates, can you at least revisit the one you're marking as "original"? It's had no activity from mods/founders for years, despite being originally summarily "declined" without any explanation whatsoever and otherwise attracting overwhelming community support.